# are there any changes in actions-sdk of actions-on-google that breaks previous codes.?

Tags: actions-on-google

Iam using `Actions SDK` to create an `actions on google` assistant app. I've created a project successfully and deployed to google actions (firebase for API), It used to work as expected in the simulator. But lately the when ever I test the app, the MAIN intent is triggered successfully which is fine, but the rest of the conversation is not sent to the API, the rest of the conversation is takenover by google, Don't know why.

Here is the conversation I tried

```
[me:]talk to my test app
[actions:] Hello Ravi, Welcome to your test app
[me:]I need to buy some clothes
[actions:] Sure, I found some pictures for you (this is no my data, this conversation is not being triggered from my external API, I don't see any API being triggered, but Im getting this message)
```

To avoid the chance that there might be a broken code from my end, I tried https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-say-number-nodejs code. its not working either.

So my question is :
**Are there any recent changes in the actions-on-google that might have broken something ?** I was able to setup `actionssdk-say-number-nodejs` using the same instructions in the README.md before, but now it gives me weird errors(firebase deploy throws errors, so I was using `firebase serve --only functions , and using ngrok to create fulfilment API)

Here is the output from that numbers demo

[image]

**UPDATE**

I'm able to make a Call to the API successfully and getting the response I needed, but the google is not responding the same. Here is the code I used to send a message "12" and it

**Request**

```
curl -X POST  -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -H "Google-Actions-API-Version: 2" https://mysitexxx.com/googleBot -d '{"user":{"userId":"ABwppHFnb3A--t4hBOstJLDgWZUrFJv4uku1ClJhv8dHtdZvUolLXGbTA_SWyM8ulvjcbCsBy3Fvhaw","locale":"en-US","lastSeen":"2017-12-11T09:22:58Z"},"conversation":{"conversationId":"1512984211990","type":"NEW"},"inputs":[{"intent":"actions.intent.TEXT","rawInputs":[{"inputType":"KEYBOARD","query":"12"}]}],"surface":{"capabilities":[{"name":"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"},{"name":"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"}]},"isInSandbox":true,"availableSurfaces":[{"capabilities":[{"name":"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"},{"name":"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"}]}]}'
```

and I get back response saying " You said 12"

**Response**

```
{"conversationToken":"{\"state\":null,\"data\":{}}","expectUserResponse":true,"expectedInputs":[{"inputPrompt":{"initialPrompts":[{"ssml":"<speak>You said, <say-as interpret-as=\"ordinal\">12</say-as></speak>"}],"noInputPrompts":[{"ssml":"I didn't hear that."},{"ssml":"If you're still there, say that again."},{"ssml":"We can stop here. See you soon."}]},"possibleIntents":[{"intent":"actions.intent.TEXT"}]}]}
```

**BUT THIS RESPONSE DOESN'T SHOW UP IN THE SIMULATOR; Actually when I type 12 from actions simulator my API is not receiving the request from simulator**

Comment: I have to say for me everything works so I would say did you double checked your action.json. Is the general TEXT intent handling inside correct? That would be my only idea right now.

Comment: I'm using the exact code from that repo . And changed the endpoint url in the action.json  and updated the changed to project using `gaction` command.. everything was working 3 days ago. But suddenly this issue.. did you try this recently ?

Comment: actually I am just develop with the google action.json and create my JSON response directly by myself and also not on firebase but on my own server. So the only part I use as well is the Google Action Backend. Witch send the right intents to my server, so the Main or everything else TEXT intent. And than I respond and the next message is still working perfectly a whole conversation long.

Comment: @shortQuestion yes that should be the behaviour, but this is what the result turns out in my case. something must be not right..